# Multiple event topics in OSGi Declarative Service component description

Tags: xml, events, osgi, apache-karaf, declarative-services

I'm sure it's really simple, but I fail to understand the required XML schema to make my component listen to multiple event topics in the OSGi framework.

I want to handle the following 2 events and at some point even more:

```
basm/event/IAM
basm/event/COV
```

I tried stuff like this

```
<properties name="event.topics">
    <entry>basm/event/IAM</entry>
    <entry>basm/event/COV</entry>
</properties>
```

or

```
<property name="event.topics" type="String" value="basm/event/IAM,basm/event/COV" />
```

or

```
<property name="event.topics" type="String" value="basm/event/IAM" />
<property name="event.topics" type="String" value="basm/event/COV" />
```

Unfortunately my OSGi book only ever uses one event topic and I surprisingly couldn't find anything on the net. I tried to go by the XML schema for DS component description but failed to understand it: http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/scr/v1.2.0/scr.xsd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

`<property name="event.topics">
basm/event/IAM
basm/event/COV
</property>`

See 112.4.6 in the OSGi spec.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that did it! Just one of those issues you hate to sink a lot time into...

Comment: @bj-hargrave how would you declare it if it was a BND Component annotation? Thanks

Comment: You can do that using a property list with multiple properties with the same name: property={"event.topics=some/topic","event.topics=another/topic"}

Answer (score 0):

You can use list of values like this :

```
<service ref="beanRef" interface="org.osgi.service.event.EventHandler">
    <service-properties>
        <entry key="event.topics">
            <list>
                <value type="java.lang.String">com/company/topic/name1</value>                    
                <value type="java.lang.String">com/company/topic/name2</value> 
            </list>                
        </entry>
    </service-properties>
</service>
```